# Trying to add two vectors but it is adding in the wrong order

Tags: c++, class, vector

In this function i'm working on the goal is to add the coefficients of polynomials, the coefficients are stored in vectors. P is a private member of the class Polynom that I have made. "RHS" is not a member of the class - it is another instance of the class, so I can still access all of its private members, like RHS.P[i]. This is the code that I have so far.
                        `

```
          Polynom Polynom::operator+(const Polynom& RHS) cons
          vector <int> temp;
          vector <int> temp2;
          vector <int> temp3;


for (int i = 0; i <= P.size()-1; i ++)
{
    temp.push_back(P[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i <= RHS.P.size()-1; i ++)
{
    temp2.push_back(RHS.P[i]);
}

int largerPoly = P.size()-1;

for (int i = 0; i <= P.size()-1; i++)
{
  if(largerPoly == RHS.P.size()-1)
  {
    temp3.push_back(temp2[largerPoly - i]);
  }
    else
    {
    temp3.push_back(temp[i]);
    }
    largerPoly --;
}
 return Polynom(temp3);




                       `
```

So for example if I input in my P vector: (4)(2)(-1)(2)(0)(0)(2)

And in the other vector:                                   (-4)(0)(1)

The resulting vector should be: (4)(2)(-1)(2)(-4)(0)(3) (1+2)=3  (0+-4)=-4

Which basically means I want to add the vector from the back (hopefully that makes sense)

unfortunately that's not the output i'm getting with this code. Any tips on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make it easier and simply split the two cases:

```
Polynom Polynom::operator+(const Polynom& arg) const
{
    const auto &lhs = this->P; // define some shorthand refs
    const auto &rhs = RHS.P;

    std::vector<int> res;

    // case 1: lhs is larger
    if (lhs.size() > rhs.size()) {
        res.assign(lhs.begin(), lhs.end()); // copy lhs into res

        auto offset = lhs.size() - rhs.size();

        for (auto i = 0; i < rhs.size(); i++) {
            res[i + offset] += rhs[i];
        }
    }
    // case 2: rhs is larger
    else {
        res.assign(rhs.begin(), rhs.end()); // copy lhs into res

        auto offset = rhs.size() - lhs.size();

        for (auto i = 0; i < lhs.size(); i++) {
            res[i + offset] += lhs[i];
        }
    }

    return Polynom(res);
}
```

Using references also means, that we do not have to copy the whole data in several local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Store your coefficients in the reverse order.

```
x^3 + x + 1 == 1 + x + x^3 <=> [1, 1, 0, 1]
```

And now all your terms will always line up and the coefficient of `x^n` is at index `n`.